# How to set the current time as static variable using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to set the current date and time in static variable.

```
I need to insert the 50 records into database table. Here,I need to insert the current date and time. Then, I need to set the current date and time of the 50 records are same. I used this  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); format. This format will change every minutes and seconds.
```

How to I do. Please help me.

Comment: why you want this?? use a variable `$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.. it will store current date and time in `$variable`, and use `$variable` in all 50 insert queries.. so all time it will be same..

Answer (score 0):

```
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

then use this variable,for create records. All records will have same time.

Comment: I need to insert the same datetime and time are all records. using $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') , the minutes and seconds change or not?

Comment: $date variable will save value of date; and then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but I found a simple solution. Maybe it's useful for someone (like me) that wants to do the same thing nowadays.
Even when you store the current time/datetime to a variable, the time it's still running, so it changes every second.
I solved it by storing the *time()* value into a MySQL table (datetime type of course), so the captured time will be stored as it is and stop running and changing every second. Then, when I want to use it, I just make a query from the MySQL table.
It's a simple way (for me) to capture the "now" value and make it stop running, but maybe there's a better way.